# How does ipfs discover peers for the first time?

Tags: distributed, ipfs

I know that in ipfs the peers and their addresses are stored in DHTs. However I can not find info about the first connection of a peer to ipfs DHTs. How can a new peer know the location of DHTs so it can connect to them and get other peers data and addresses?